# Greasemonkey: How to remove random url parts?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4

I need to change images like this from...

`https://www.website.com/images/stuff/95/jgfij/public/2019/09/cow.gif
https://www.website.com/images/stuff/df3/4gy0/public/2015/03/horse.png
https://www.website.com/images/stuff/odpk/f049/public/2020/08/dog.jpg`

into...

`https://www.website.com/images/stuff/public/2019/09/cow.gif
https://www.website.com/images/stuff/public/2015/03/horse.png
https://www.website.com/images/stuff/public/2020/08/dog.jpg`

I tried this but it doesn't work

`document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('https://www.website.com/images/stuff/*/public/,'https://www.website.com/images/stuff/public/');`

I've been trying to find something that remove everything inbetween a certain part of the url and I've never had any luck.

Comment: Please read the tag for greasemonkey. It's been obsolete for years.

Comment: This isn't relevant to your question, but Tampermonkey might be a valid replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Your example probably wasn't quite what you wanted. Maybe the following:

```
blahblahblah.replace(new RegExp('https://www.website.com/images/stuff/.*/public/'),
    'https://www.website.com/images/stuff/public/');
```

You were missing an endquote on the regex, and had `/*`, which means "zero or more slashes" when you probably want `.*`, "zero or more of any character".

I also discovered that you have to pass in the pattern as a regex, not a string. See comment below.

Comment: I appreciate the help but it didn't work. Would it matter if I used (.*) or [.*]?

Comment: No, sorry, the problem is that String.replace(), when you pass in the first value as a String, it does a literal string replacement, not a regex replacement. You have to pass in the first value as a regex object. Just a sec, I'll update my answer. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Okie dokie. Try now.,

Comment: Still doesn't work.  

It works when I do this  

`document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('https://www.website.com/f/styles/84ht879ht478/public/all/',
    'https://www.website.com/f/all/');`  

but I'd have to do a bunch of them

Comment: You have to use a RegExp() or a /blahblahblah/ regular expression literal, not a string as your first argument. What does console.log(document.body.innerHTML) show you?